# Any caveats in porting GNU Pth code for Pthreads?

Tags: c, winapi, pthreads, gnu

I have code written using GNU Pth ( http://www.gnu.org/software/pth/ ) and I want to move to Pthreads because I want it to be cross-platform (Unix, Mac, Windows).

Are there and caveats I should watch out for while going about switching from Pth to Pthreads, or is it mostly just a matter of realigning arguments and variable types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to let people know: it is a fairly easy transition. Some of the naming is different, and there are slight differences in argument number and order but they are very similar overall.

Just look up the api docs for both and look up what they do and then compare it to the other api docs.